# Can't make new unlisted resolution, BadMatch error

Tags: xubuntu, xrandr

I just installed Xubuntu 17.10, and I quite like it, but my monitor's native resolution won't show up (1920x1080)
Even if I try to make and add a new resolution via xrandr it outputs the following:

```
levente@levente-H97-HD3:~$ cvt -r 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.93 Hz (CVT 2.07M9-R) hsync: 66.59 kHz; pclk: 138.50 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080R"  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync
levente@levente-H97-HD3:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080R"  138.50 1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync
levente@levente-H97-HD3:~$ xrandr --addmode 1920x1080R 
xrandr: --addmode requires two arguments
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.
levente@levente-H97-HD3:~$ xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1920x1080R 
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  37
Current serial number in output stream:  38
levente@levente-H97-HD3:~$
```

It's not a VM, runs artful

Update: Driver can't read EDID data

```
[    25.350] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    25.350] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select" 
[    25.350] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1024 
x 768
[    25.354] (WW) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0 does not have an EDID, or its EDID does not contain a
[    25.354] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     maximum image size; cannot compute DPI from CRT-0's EDID.
[    25.354] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
```

This is because I am using an SVGA to DVI-D converter

Update: Found a tool to overwrite edid data, but I can't find the right bin for my monitor (LG Flatron E2260)
[edid overwrite tool](https://github.com/bulletmark/edid-rw)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the nouveau drivers and forcing the resolution with xrandr...

NVIDIA's drivers wouldn't let me use xrandr for some reason